# Icons not being displayed in Angular Material List

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am attempting to display a list of the names of users of my application. Included 
in the display is supposed to be an icon button which will perform some action
when pressed. I am using Angular Material components.

I believe I have all the important imports to the module. The code below shows
the material design components I imported:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatToolbarModule,
         MatCardModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import { routeCmp } from './app.router';
import { NewuserModule } from './newuser/newuser.module';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  // the rest of the code omitted for brevity
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Based on examples I've seen on the Internet, I have the following HTML for my 
display:

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let names of userNames">
        <div matLine>{{ names }}</div>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Note that userNames is (currently) just an array of strings.

My code is similar to the code shown below, which is taken from an example at
https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples?file=app%2Fnav-list%2Fnav-list.component.html

```
<h5>Complex Nav List</h5>
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let link of links">
        <a matLine href="javascript:void(0)">{{ link }}</a>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
         </button>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

The display from the example is shown in the picture below:

[image: Good icon display]

Unfortunately, what I am seeing instead is a button and text:

[image]

Obviously, I am missing something. There is something not described in the example  that
makes it work. I did try recreating the example code in my own development setup, based
on what I downloaded from the site. The example code failed to properly display the 
icon in my environment.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here? How can I get my list to properly display
the icons in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import Material Icons fonts into your project.

In `index.html`, add the following code.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Since you are using `mat-icon-button`, you also need to import `MatButtonModule` into your `AppModule` imports.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing the `MatButtonModule` in your AppModule's imports.